# Find by id with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I would like to find a data by `_id`. I know that this data exists and that this `_id` exist (I've tested it with pymongo).

But the code below doesn't find it:

```
type id_cookie struct {
    IdCookie int
}

func get_id_mongo() int {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("id_bag").C("id_cookie")
    data := id_cookie{}
    err2 := c.FindId(bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex("58593d1d6aace357b32bb3a1")}).One(&data)
    if (err2 != nil){
        Info.Println("error")
        Info.Println(err2)
    }
    Info.Println(data)
    return data.IdCookie
}
```

It just returns me a `0`.

But I can find it using pytmongo and python.

```
import requests
import pymongo 
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from pprint import pprint
client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 27017)

import base64



db = client.id_bag
pprint(db.collection_names())
result = db.id_cookie.insert_one(
    { 'IdCookie': 1
    })
print(result.inserted_id)

data = db.id_cookie.find_one({"_id": ObjectId("58593d1d6aace357b32bb3a1")})
print(data)
```

here are the result :

```
['id_cookie', 'system.indexes']
58593d2d6aace357b32bb3a3
{'IdCookie': 1, '_id': ObjectId('58593d1d6aace357b32bb3a1')}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Edit :
i've try with :

```
err2 := c.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex("58593d1d6aace357b32bb3a1")).One(&data)
```

but i still have 0 :

```
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:08 Cookie_Id.go:147: 1
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:08 Cookie_Id.go:149: 2
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:87: data
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:88: {0}
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:89: 0
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:118: 0
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:128: OK
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You either use [`Collection.FindId()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.FindId) and then you pass only the id value, or you use [`Collection.Find()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Find) and then you have to specify a value with the field name too:

```
err2 := c.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex("58593d1d6aace357b32bb3a1")).One(&data)

// OR
err2 := c.Find(bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex("58593d1d6aace357b32bb3a1")}).
    One(&data)
```

If you get no errors, that means the document is found.

If you always see `0` printed (as the value of the `id_cookie.IdCookie` field), that means the field in the document holding this id has a different name.

Use [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to tell how it is stored in your MongoDB. E.g. if in your MongoDB it is called `"myid"`, you can map it like this:

```
type id_cookie struct {
    IdCookie int `bson:"myid"`
}
```

Also note that you should not connect to the MongoDB server every time you want to query some data, instead connect once, and just reuse the session. for details see: [mgo - query performance seems consistently slow (500-650ms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999637/mgo-query-performance-seems-consistently-slow-500-650ms/41000876#41000876)

Comment: Thanks for the note  but IdCookie is not _id

Comment: @user462794 Please see edited answer. If you use `FindId()`, you only have to pass the id value (and not wrapped in a `bson.M`). Or use `Find()` and then you can pass id wrapped in `bson.M`.

Comment: I still have 0 :   INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:08 Cookie_Id.go:147: 1
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:08 Cookie_Id.go:149: 2
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:87: data
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:88: {0}
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:89: 0
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:118: 0
INFO: 2016/12/20 15:42:18 Cookie_Id.go:128: OK

Comment: @user462794 The code I posted works (verified). There must be something else you've not showed us and is different.

Comment: it was the :   IdCookie int `bson:"IdCookie"` thanks a lot

Comment: it does not work I am guessing something is wrong with the insert, I cannot select it via _id